# Javascript/XML - Getting the node name

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, dom

I need to get the the name of the tag "myChild" and the "content".
This is simple, but i am stuck, sleepy and here is what I get with my tests:

XML:

```
...
<myParent>
  <myChild>content</myChild>
</myParent>
<myParent>
  <myChild>content</myChild>
</myParent>
...
```

JS:

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("myParent");
alert(x[1].childNodes[0].nodeName); //returns "#text" - "myChild" needed
alert(x[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue); //returns "" - "content" needed
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>You want `tagName`, which is the name of the element.</s> *(Sorry about that, for `Element`s, `tagName` and `nodeName` are the same.)*

The problem is that the first child of your `myParent` element isn't the `myChild` element, it's a text node (containing whitespace). Your structure looks like this:

- Element "myParent"

  - Text node with a carriage return and some spaces or tabs
  - Element "myChild"

    - Text node with "content"
  - Text node with a carriage return and some spaces or tabs
- Element "myParent"

  - Text node with a carriage return and some spaces or tabs
  - Element "myChild"

    - Text node with "content"
  - Text node with a carriage return and some spaces or tabs

You need to navigate down to the actual `myChild` element, which you can do with `getElementsByTagName` again, or just by scanning:

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("myParent");
var c = x[1].firstChild;
while (c && c.nodeType != 1) { // 1 = ELEMENT_NODE
    c = c.nextSibling;
}
alert(c.nodeName); // "myChild"
```

Note that `Element`s don't have a meaningful `nodeValue` property; instead, you collect their child text nodes. (More in the DOM specs: [DOM2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/), [DOM3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/).)

Also note that when indexing into a `NodeList`, the indexes start at `0`. You seem to have started with `1`; ignore this comment if you were skipping the first one for a reason.

---

**Off-topic**: It's always best to understand the underlying mechanics of what you're working with, and I do recommend playing around with the straight DOM and referring to the DOM specs listed above. But for interacting with these trees, a good library can be really useful and save you a lot of time. [jQuery](http://jquery.com) works well with XML data. I haven't used any of the others like [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) with XML, so can't speak to that, but I expect at least some of them support it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `x[1].getElementsByTagName('*')[0]` instead.

(This is only trustable for index 0, other indexes may return elements that are not child-nodes, if the direct childs contain further element-nodes. )